# Can e-mails that were recently deleted through the “delete message” rule action in Apple Mail still be recovered?

Tags: mail.app, high-sierra, data-recovery, mail-rules

I recently set up a rule in Apple Mail with “delete message” as the action. Unfortunately, I made a mistake in the conditions of the rule. And to my dismay, “delete message” really seems to immediately delete the e-mails, not just move them to the trash folder as I had thought. So I’ve lost a number of e-mails I had not intended to delete. I’m guessing the answer to my question is probably “no”, but just in case it’s not: is there any way I might still be able to recover some of those e-mails?

The following screenshot is from a [Mac Observer article](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/sort-block-emails-apple-mail-macos/) that illustrates the use of the “delete message” rule action.

[image]

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2264667

Comment: Time machine backup?

Comment: @JBis: thanks for the link to the discussion thread on Apple Communities, that at least confirms that the e-mails being immediately deleted is not a bug, but the intended behavior of the action. I will check Time Machine again, but as the e-mails never made it to my “Inbox” folder, I doubt they are to be found in its backup copy. I was thinking more along the lines of some temporary cache file, or something like that, that might still hold a copy.

Comment: No problem. FYI TM does usually backup cache.